# scrapy docs author spider couldn't crawl internal link

Tags: hyperlink, scrapy, web-crawler, internals

I tried the `AuthorSpider` in scrapy docs, but it doesn't return the author page for me, it even doesn't go to `parse_author()` method, I want to crawl a website with several internal links, then follow the link to crawl the article, I tried all the scrapy code to use `response.follow()` with several parse method, but it only called the first `parse()` method, the `parse_author()` method never get called.

Comment: Are you using the exactly same code from the docs (https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#more-examples-and-patterns)?
Looks like you are trying to crawl a different website, in this case the sample code will not work.

Comment: @LuizRodriguesdaSilva Thank you for answering.  I used the same code to try the example, it just crawled the url for me without going further to get the author info.

Comment: Please, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve